# Return primitive data type from a catch block in java

Tags: java

i'm playing around with exceptions for learning purposes and i have a question. Please see the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print(getNumber());

}


public static double getNumber() {

    double number =10;

    try {
        String [] students = {"nick","george"};
        System.out.println(students[5]);
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex ) {
        System.out.println("In catch block "+ number);
        return number;
    }
    finally {
        number +=10;
        System.out.println("The value is now "+ number);
    }
    System.out.println("hiiiii");
    return number;
}
```

Why in this case the output from the main method will be 10 and why if i run the same example and return an object the value will be changed?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("In main  is "+getStringBuffer());
}



public static StringBuffer getStringBuffer() {

    StringBuffer number = new StringBuffer("10");

    try {
        String [] names= {"george" ,"nick"};
        System.out.println(names[5]);
    }

    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex1) {
        System.out.println("In catch block "+ number);
        return number;
    }

    finally {
    number.reverse();   
        System.out.println("In finally is "+ number);
    }
    System.out.println("hiiii");
    return number;
}
```

Comment: *"...why if i run the same example and return an object the value will be changed?"* Huh? Can you show us what you mean? What kind of object?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is what i mean..please take a look at the edited question now

Comment: @notArefill: Ah, because you're changing the state of the object, not the value being returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value returned by the method is set as of the `return` statement it encounters. So

```
return number;
```

**does not** mean "remember that you're going to return the `number` variable", it means "evaluate the `number` variable, and remember the resulting value to use it as the return value". Changing the contents of the `number` variable later (in the `finally` block) has no effect on the value being returned by the method, that's already been determined.

How do we know this? Because `return` has to evaluate the expression (per [§14.17 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17)). Suppose, for instance, you had

```
return number + 5;
```

...you wouldn't expect to get `25` because you had `10`, hit the `return` statement, then added another `10` in the `finally` block, and then the expression added `5` more, right? `return` evaluates the expression and remembers that **value** as the method's return value.

In the object example you give, the *value* being returned isn't being changed in the `finally` block. It's still just a reference to the object. You're changing the *state* of the object whose reference is being returned, but the reference is not being changed. If you replaced

```
number.reverse();
```

with

```
number = new StringBuffer();
```

...you'd see that you get exactly the same behavior as with a `double`, because in that case, you're changing the **value** held in `number` (the reference to the object), just like you do with `number += 10;`.

Answer (score 3):

Because in the first example, you are returning a primitive and its return value is already on the stack and cannot be changed by the finally block.

In the second example, you are returning a reference variable and the value it points to can be changed by the finally block.

Answer (score 2):

The `catch` block runs before the `finally` block.  In the primitive version of the code,  when the `return` occurs, the value of that variable is still 10, so that is what is returned.

In the second version of the code, you're returning a `StringBuffer`, but you're editing the contents of that `StringBuffer`.  So although there's just one `StringBuffer`, which you're returning, by the time the calling method gets to see the returned object, it has already been updated.

Another way of looking at this is that in the second case, the thing being returned is a reference, to an object that's sitting in the heap; but in the first case, you're actually returning a value, not a reference.

Answer (score 0):

**first Question:** Why in this case the output from the main method will be 10.

Because you attempting to access the value which is not available .

Reason:  String [] students = {"nick","george"};

herestudents array size is 2 and you are attempting to access the 5th element as below:

```
  System.out.println(students[5]);
```

by calling above statement java throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

as you are catching the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` Exception all statements inside the catch block will be executed.

here you are printing the number value as below:

```
System.out.println("In catch block "+ number);
```

which will print the number which is `10.`

Comment: i understand that,my question is why in the first case i can't change the value and why when i have an object i can.